# python: what is the opposite of id()

Tags: python

In Python `id('some text')` returns the “identity” of an object.
Is there a function that takes a number as argument that can access an item by identity?

e.g.:

```
print(object_at(id('some text')+1))
```

Comment: Why would you add 1 to that number? Accessing arbitrary memory locations will cause an access violation (0xC0000005 on Windows)

Comment: Not that doesn't rely on implementation details. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: iterate over all identities

Comment: Wait, why are you adding 1???

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What does +1 have to do with that? Please explain with more details

Comment: The closest thing provided by Python is `gc.get_objects()`, which will return a list of all live objects.  You can call `id()` on that list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not one id()+x

Comment: @Frank Yellin the idea is to reverse the action of id() and get an object based on the unique identity

Comment: @dsl400 **that's what I'm asking**. Why are you adding 1 to the id?

Comment: just for fun! is there a reason why I should not ask this kind of questions ?

Comment: ok, no addition!  `var_a = 'some string' var_b=id(var_a)` is there any solution to get the string from var_a using the value of var_b  ?

Comment: @dsl400 did you look at the duplicate question? Warning: this is a really bad idea.